# Python: flattening a zip?

Tags: python

I have two list that I want to zip:

```
a = ((1,2,3), (4,5,6), ... )
h = ('a','b', ... )
```

A simple `zip(a,h)` returns this:

```
[ ((1,2,3),'a'), ((4,5,6),'b'), ... ]
```

Is there any clever way to return this?

```
[ (1,2,3,'a'), (4,5,6,'b'), ... ]
```

Comment: Definitely not the best way, but probably the shortest: `zip(*(zip(*a)+[h]))`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use tuple concatenation in a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))
>>> h = ('a', 'b')
>>> [x + (y,) for x, y in zip(a, h)]
[(1, 2, 3, 'a'), (4, 5, 6, 'b')]
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are using python 3.5 or higher, you can use the [additional unpacking generalizations (PEP 448)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations):

```
    In [24]: [(*one,two) for one, two in zip(((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)) ,('a','b'))]
    Out[24]: [(1, 2, 3, 'a'), (4, 5, 6, 'b')]
```

Comment: Works only with Python 3.4+

Comment: ah yes, my ipython defaults to 3.x

Comment: @Daniel: [Python 3.5+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations) perhaps?

Answer (score 7):

You could use a "nested" tuple destructuring:

```
a = ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))
h = ('a', 'b')
out = [(x, y, z, c) for (x, y, z), c in zip(a, h)]
```

Comment: Clever. Thank you.

Comment: But this assumes `a` will hold tuples of only 3 elements

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I believe that is a fair assumption to make given the OPs question. If you are dealing with a list of tuples of different lengths or with tuples with more than five or so elements, eugene y's answer is the way to go.

Comment: @pzp I would also mark this one as correct, but the other guy was faster. They're both good solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution if `a` items' length is fixed to 3:

```
a = ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))
h = ('a', 'b')

[(x[0], x[1], x[2], y) for x, y in zip(a, h)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use chain from itertools:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = ((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9) )
>>> h = ('a','b', 'c' )
>>> [ tuple(chain(x,y)) for x,y in zip(a,h) ]
[(1, 2, 3, 'a'), (4, 5, 6, 'b'), (7, 8, 9, 'c')]
```

Comment: This relies on elements of `h` being iterable. Try `h = ('a', 'b', 3)` for example.